# Count db result from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want count the result from table.

Table looks like this(row data),

[image]

Que is question and answer is Answer, and answer most have a value of 1 to 5, but it can vary depending on the question.(like 1 to 9)

The image above is only part and the question is from 1 to 13.
The rows in the table repeat over and over again.

I'd like to know the percentage of answers to each question.

I try to count,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM survey.surveys WHERE exhibition_id = 2 GROUP BY que;
```

But this is just count by que

How I can count it?

---

I want result like,

```
que | answer | count(answer)
 1  |   1    |    30
 1  |   2    |    27
 1  |   3    |    28
 1  |   4    |    31
 1  |   5    |    30
 2  |   1    |    17
 2  |   2    |    23
 2  |   3    |    31
 2  |   4    |    45
 2  |   5    |    29
```

Comment: "'d like to know the percentage of answers to each question." - what does this mean? Please provide example desired output results.

Comment: @Dai Attached to the question.

Comment: @Dai Sorry, It's simple of that. Thanks you for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group by answers

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM survey.surveys WHERE exhibition_id = 2 GROUP BY answers`

Comment: But in that case, the result does not take into account the question.

Comment: You can add case when statement according your wish

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: Sorry, It's simple of that. Thanks you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT que,answer,count(answer) FROM survey.surveys WHERE exhibition_id = 2 GROUP by answer order by que asc
```